# Why does Netty's ExecutorUtil.terminate() call ExecutionHandler.shutdownNow()?

Tags: java, netty

I've to manage a client-server-application with > 1K connected clients using netty 3.5.1. Sometimes updates get lost which are written to database when we disconnect our clients through restarting our servers. When performing a restart/shutdown, we shutdown our Netty components like this:

- shutdown server-channel
- disconnect all clients (via ChannelGroupFuture)
- call releaseExternalResources() on our ChannelPipeline
- call releaseExternalResources() on our ExecutionHandler which is part of our ChannelPipeline (is it necessary to invoke it manually?)

However I wonder why ExecutorUtil.*terminate* (which is called by the ExecutionHandler) does a *shutdownNow* on the passed ExecutorService, because *shutdownNow* drains all existing tasks in the queue and returns them. The tasks won't be executed because ExecutorUtil.*terminate* is of type *void*. Wouldn't it be more appropriate to invoke *shutdown* on the ExecutorService and wait for the completion?

Answer (score 0):

That's a good suggestion.. Would you mind open a issue for it on our issue tracker[1]

[1 ]https://github.com/netty/netty/issues